# ¿Como escribir en el panel de consola de sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Paso a explicar mejor el problema que tengo al escribir en la consola que trae por defecto sublime text 3. Resulta que para poder hacer eso, he creado en *tools-buils syetem-new buils system*, un archivo *.sublime-build* con
el nombre prueba, y lo ejecuto con las teclas ctrl + B, el codigo que pongo en el archivo *.sublime-build* es el siguiente.
`**{ "shell_cmd": "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe" }**`

El cual escribe en la ventana de consola de sublime text 3, (hola mundo 1), hasta ahi todo perfecto, el problema es  que cada ves que presiono ctrl + B, se crean mas procesos hola.exe, (aclaro que hola se llama la aplicacion, osea no se cierra el anterior hola.exe, por ejemplo si presiono 5 veces ctrl + B, se crean 5 veces el proceso hola.exe.

Que puedo agregar a mi codigo para que cuando presione ctrl + B, se cierre el anterior hola.exe, y asi mantener un solo hola.exe en ejecucion?. Espero se entienda mi pregunta, y desde ya muchas gracias.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Uwe.png]

Comment: esta va a ser una pregunta tonta... pero si ejecutas a mano el exe se queda abierto? o se cierra sin que hagas nada? parece mas un problema del exe que de sbt3

Comment: Ante todo muchas gracias por su ayuda, y en cuanto a su respuesta, tienes mucha razon, no me habia dado cuanta de eso. El codigo que puse sirve para abrir el .exe en el panel de consola de sublime text 3, supongo que debe haber algun codigo o comando para cerrar el .exe, cual podria ser la solucion?

Comment: Que yo sepa no lo hay. Puedes lanzar una cmd que busque el proceso y lo mate

Comment: Tiene que haber alguna linea de codigo que pueda agregar para matar el proceso, en mi caso yo no lo se, porque el lenguaje que usa sublime text 3 para crear archivos .sublime-build es json, y yo no se usar ese lenguaje, yo manejo c sharp, supongo que en json debe haber algo como exit(), close(), o lo que fuera, alguien que maneje json me puede ayudar? se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Como se lanza en el lenguaje json un cmd para matar un proceso? quizas funcione esa idea, no conosco la sintaxis de json, podrias poner un ejemplo? osea escribir el codigo que yo puse, mas el codigo que llame a cmd para que mate el proceso

Comment: Quiero corregir la pregunta anterior que hice, en sublime text 3 los archivos .sublime-build se crean con lenguaje python, aunque creo que tambien en json, pero igual te todos modos no manejo ninguno de esos 2 lenguajes, por eso necesito ayuda